# How to keep image size when changing iPhone orientation

Tags: iphone, css, html

I have an image that's 575x300px with text inside it.

While the iPhone is in the landscape position everything's dandy, but change the orientation to portrait and the image 'shrinks' in size (resolution change?) and the text becomes unreadable.

Is there a way to maintain the image size for both orientations?

Edit - I'm talking about a web page, not an app.

Comment: are you using uiwebview or uiimageview?

Answer (score 0):

Set the view's `contentMode` to the value you would like. You probably want a value like `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the autoresizing mask property for the UIImageView to UIViewAutoresizngmasknone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm talking about an image within a webpage, not an app.